# Mapping a list of strings to a grouped map

Tags: groovy, collections

I need to get two integers from a string, use the second as key, first as value and then group them based on their keys. Currently I have this.

```
def partitioned = input.groupBy{it[0] =='v'}
        def groupedResult = partitioned[true].collect { (it =~ /\w+ (\d+) (?:\w+ ){3}(\d+)/)[0] }.collect { [it[2].toInteger(), it[1].toInteger()] }.groupBy { it[0] }.collectEntries { k, v -> [k, v.collect { it[1] }] }.withDefault { new ArrayList<Integer>() }
        def left = partitioned[false].toSet()
```

Is there a better way to do this using the standard library methods?

I thought of trying to use `subMap` and `collectEntires` but then the types got messed up and I did not know what to do

For example if I have

```
Vyz 15 blah blah blah 23
VBC 25 Foo bar Baz 37
Vqr 17 brr brr brr 23
```

I would need to get a `[23:[15,17], 37:[25]]`

Comment: Without example inputs and expected output for each, this question is unanswerable

Comment: I have edited the post with an example input. Would you be able to help me now?

Answer (score 1):

You could use inject like so:

```
def result = input
  .findAll { it.startsWith 'V' }
  .collect { it.split('\\s+')[1, 5].collect { it as Integer } }
  .inject([:].withDefault { [] as Set }) { map, values ->
      map[values[1]] << values[0]
      map
  }
```